# dynamic slideshow of files(of any type)

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ajax

I have some files (images, pdf, text) in a folder.
Say my files are:

- image1.jpg
- image2.jpg
- pdf1.pdf
- text1.txt

in folder "Files".
Now I want to display each file with custom time, which means for example

1. image1.jpg - 5 sec
2. image2.jpg - 10sec
3. pdf1.pdf  - 20sec
4. text1.txt - 15 sec

assuming I have my file path and file time as key => value in `array`

how can I do this?

I have tried doing this in php and javascript

> ```
> <script>
>
> function display_time(param1)
> {
>   var time=param1*60*1000;
>   var res=setTimeout(doHide,time);
>   function doHide(){
>       document.getElementById("file").style.display = "none";
>
>   }
>
> }
>
>
> <?php
> **// assume i have my file path and file time in $input respectively**
>     $image_ext=["jpg","png"];
>   $file_path=array_keys($input); 
>   $file_time=array_values($input);
>   $i=0;
>
>   for($i;$i<count($input);$i++){
>   $ext= pathinfo($file_path[$i],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
>   echo '<div class="section" style="max-width:800px">';
>   if(in_array($ext,$GLOBALS['image_ext'])){
>   echo '<img src= '.$file_path[$i].' alt = "This image cant be loaded" style="width:800px" id="file">';
>   echo '<script>display_time('.$file_time[$i].');</script>';
>
>   }
>   elseif(($ext=="txt")){
>   echo '<p id="file">'.file_get_contents($file_path[$i]).'</p>';
>   echo '<script>display_time('.$file_time[$i].');</script>';
>
>   }
>   elseif($ext == 'pdf'){
>   echo '<embed src='.$file_path[$i].' width="800px" height="2500px" id="file"/>';
>   echo '<script>display_time('.$file_time[$i].');</script>';
>
>   }
>   echo '</div>';
>   }
>
> ?>
> ```

Comment: you may create a json file and read each file custom time.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [materialize](http://materializecss.com/carousel.html)

with simple code like:

```
<div class="carousel">
<a class="carousel-item" href="#one!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/1"></a>
<a class="carousel-item" href="#two!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/2"></a>
<a class="carousel-item" href="#three!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/3"></a>
<a class="carousel-item" href="#four!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/4"></a>
<a class="carousel-item" href="#five!"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/5"></a>
```

and initilize it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.carousel').carousel();
});
```

Hope that's what u need!

Comment: hi, I think I cant use this because each file has a different time value and my number of files(images, pdf etc..) varies each time I run the script. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make an object for each file
Example

```
let objArray = [
{
url = '/file.jpg',
time = 5
}
.....
]
```

Then make a `setTimeout` and put there object time value

```
settimeout(function(){
...
}, objArray[n].time*1000);
```

Comment: hi, yes I have done in this similar manner. I have created an array in which key is file and value is the time and then I have called setTimeout(function(), time) where the function is to hide the element in that time but it only works on the first element I am not getting why?

Comment: Dont you think its because you use same ID for different containers?

Comment: Thanks for your time. I figured this out.

Comment: So, check my answer)